# Play vimeo in expo-av

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

Learning app and i want to play the video's with expo-av

All our videos are on vimeo but i cant get it to work in expo-av

when i past the link in the source it's not working.

so what i have done is installed webview and did this

```
<WebView
        style={style}
        allowsFullscreenVideo
        scrollEnabled={false}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
        source={{
          html: `
            <html>
              <body>
                  <div>
                      <div>
                          <div id="container" style={{paddingBottom: '56.25%', position:'relative', display:'block', width: "100%"}}>
                              <iframe id="ViostreamIframe" width="100%" height="90%"
                                  src="${item.Video}"
                                  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style={{position:'absolute', top:0, left: 0}}>
                              </iframe>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
              </body>
            </html>
          `,
        }}
      />
```

Does it work? yes...
but i want the options of expo-av.

is there a solution to this problem?

I am using an expo managed workflow btw.

Comment: Thanks for that. Have you found a solution to the problem by any chance?

Comment: Yes i found one. When you go to vimeo, when you select your video and go to distribution and scrol all the way down to the bottom you find the direct links to the video source. You can copy those and paste in expo av. works just fine